# Can I use phonegap to turn off roaming data on a user's phone?

Tags: cordova

I am currently thinking of a project using Phonegap and a feature I'd like to have is that the application determines the user's location using HTML5 geolocation and if the user isn't in their home nation the app will turn off the roaming data to prevent them incurring a large bill at the end of the month! Is this feasible in Phonegap?

Please note I am asking this as a hypothetical question and not for someone to provide code or answers, but if you have some links to examples of documentation I'd be appreciative. My searches have resulted in very little so far hence me asking.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can turn off roaming data on a user's phone.You can do this by creating a plugin for the respective platform.This plugins give us access to the native mobile environment coding.
In case of android you can achieve it by creating a plugin by using [apndroid](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/).It is open source you can check out the logic on how such logic is achieved.Phonegap is very good.You can probably do anything you want to do.